# latex notation for matrix inside matrix

Tags: annotations

could anyone help me how to write in latex a matrix like the one below? I tried for the first one but didn't get exact form.

```
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 A&0&\dots\\ 
 B&A&\dots\\
 0&B&\dots\\
\dots&\dots&\dots\\
\dots&\dots&A\\
\dots&\dots&B\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
```

[image: n]

Comment: Related: [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `pstricks`. Compile with `xelatex`, or with `pdflatex` if you use the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) ot `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,  auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\[%
\setlength\fboxrule{0pt}\setlength\fboxsep{5pt}
\setlength\arraycolsep{6pt}
 \begin{postscript}
\begin{bmatrix}
\pnode(0.2em,2ex){a} \rnode{11}{A}& \rnode{12}{0} & &  & \rnode{13}{0}\pnode(-0.2em,2ex){b}\\
 B&\rnode{22}{A}  \\
 \rnode{31}{0}&\rnode{32}{B} \\
 \\
&  & &  & \rnode{43}{A}\\
\rnode{51}{0} &  \rnode{52}{0} &  &  & \rnode{53}{B}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\psset{linestyle=dotted,  dotsep=7pt,  nodesep=9pt}
% horizontal dots
\ncline[offset=-0.7ex]{12}{13}\ncline[offset=-0.9ex]{52}{53}
% vertical dots
\ncline[nodesepB=4pt]{31}{51}\ncline[nodesepB=4pt]{32}{52}\ncline[dotsep=8pt, nodesepA =14pt]{13}{43}
%diagonal dots
\psset{nodesep=3pt, dotsep=8pt}
\ncline{22}{43}\ncline{32}{53}
 \psset{braceWidth=0.8pt, braceWidthInner=4pt, braceWidthOuter=4pt, }
\psbrace*[rot=-90](b)(a){\clap{\fbox{$\scriptstyle \varepsilon{+}1  $\enspace}}}
\end{postscript}
 \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using Kile, not getting anyhting

Comment: Did you compile with xelatex, or enable the switch?